# WebApp cannot connect to Dbaas SQL server database

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-web-apps, azure-sql

Since yesterday afternoon our Azure website is (again) not working because it cannot connect to its Azure SQL Server database.
We haven't changed anything. The database is accessible through Management Studio and when running my website (or webjobs) locally it can access the same database.
We had something similar last week as well, that time it took only a few hours.

We hardly have any error messages in our logging but we did get this one:

```
Maximum number of retries (3) exceeded while executing database operations with 'SqlAzureExecutionStrategy'. 
See inner exception for the most recent failure.
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.RetryLimitExceededException: Maximum number of retries (3) exceeded while executing database operations with 'SqlAzureExecutionStrategy'. 
See inner exception for the most recent failure. --->
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> 
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) ---> 
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Early this morning the website was still not able to log in, but just now it seems to work again. I need to know why this happened and how we can prevent this.

The health services show no problem.
The resource utilization of our elastic pool:
[image: The resource utilization of our elastic pool]
The purple areas are the moments we couldn't log in.
The 100% moments are when our data warehouse is being updated for our PowerBI Dashboards.
Other metrics in Azure show very low utilization and memory use. Because the webapp is responding, no http 5xx or 4xx are logged.

Because we don't have an additional service contract we can't submit a ticket.
We're considering upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is check service health in the Azure portal, are there any issues or events relating to the database or the web application.

Second, check the performance metrics of your database, are you hitting any limits or seeing big spikes around the time the error occurred?

Finally, if none of that helps then your going to need to raise a support ticket with MS and have them look into what occurred.

Comment: Thanks @sam-cogan. I've updated my post. In summary the metrics show no unusual spikes.